# g++ (C++) warning: statement has no effect (toggle bool != bool)

Tags: c++, toggle

I get this warning in C++ I assume.

When I try to build my program using g++

```
g++ --version
```

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
file.cpp: In function âvoid mainloop(THREAD_DATA*)â:
file.cpp:970: warning: statement has no effect
```

```
typedef
struct THREAD_DATA_
{
    struct spectate_player_t {
            bool        want_updates;   /* want player updates by specating all players every 100 milliseconds (who are in ship of course) */
            PLAYER  *last_spec_player;  /* last spectated player (just so it knows where it left off) */
            bool        direction; /* which direction spectating goes (used to avoid dead ends) so it cycles all players */ 
    } spectate[1];
} THREAD_DATA;
```

...

```
static void mainloop(THREAD_DATA *td)
```

Line 970 is just a toggle I used to think worked all the time in C++ so it's baffling me why it got removed all of a sudden or maybe the warning is useless?

```
Line 967: if(td->spectate->last_spec_player)
Line 968:    pkt_send_spectate_player(td->spectate->last_spec_player->pid);
Line 969: else
Line 970:    td->spectate->direction != td->spectate->direction;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it should be:

```
td->spectate->direction = !td->spectate->direction;
```

since `!=` is inequality operator, `a != a` is not equal to `a = !a`, it's equal to `!(a == a)`

Comment: Oh crap I totally missed that. Thanks all warnings gone now. I'll accept this as answer in 10 minutes when it allows me too.